# Examples (and metrics) of successful OO software projects

Tags: oop

I'm doing some research on the benefits of OOP to convince my faculty (mechanical engineering) to adapt a more modern approach of software development.

Despite some intensive search, I can't find examples of successful, more or less well known projects that have been done completly OO.

I understand that many projects are mixed from c and c++ and that you can create "object based" architectures with c, but surely there must be some OO-only projects to support my argumentation.

It would be nice, if you could point me to some information about such projects, maybe even some metrics.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java. Python. Just to name two extremely widely used pure OO languages. So why don't you start with Android.

Comment: Since Android is based on the linux kernel, which is not "really" OO regarding to wikipedia, I doubt that pointing at "Android" helps in my research. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: You seem to be conflating Dalvik and Android. I would suggest you do some more research...

Comment: I don't understand how researching details of Android helps in my original question. Since I'm not a native speaker I might be wrong, but you seem to be offended by my previous post. If so, please accept my apologies.

Comment: Incidentally; the Java compiler and Java itself are written in Java.